# How to get response of recurring subscription in authorize.net each time

Tags: php, authorize.net

Hy.

I have implemented code to subscribe user and get result first time in authorize.net recurring billing. How can i get result each time when payment occurs. Because i have no access after subscription got placed. I read somthing about it which said response will be given on url you specified in Merchent account after each response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The method you mention above is a Silent Post. However a better solution is to use a [Webhook](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html).  Webhooks are a modern replacement for silent post and offer a more secure and reliable method.